# Getting "PermissionError: [Errno13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\BobTheBuilder\\Desktop\\build\\build"

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, virtualbox, pyinstaller

When trying to Build my code on a Virtual Machine (Virtual Box, Windows 10) I get Errno 13.

After not working the first time I tried running CMD as admin and a few other solutions around the web with none of them making any difference.

I use the command

```
pyinstaller build DankConvoGenv2.1.2.py
```

and it produces

```
202 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
202 INFO: Python: 3.7.4
202 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
218 INFO: wrote C:\Users\BobTheBuilder\Desktop\build\build.spec
218 INFO: UPX is not available.
218 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\BobTheBuilder\\Desktop\\build',
 'C:\\Users\\BobTheBuilder\\Desktop\\build',
 'C:\\Users\\BobTheBuilder\\Desktop\\build']
218 INFO: checking Analysis
218 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
218 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
218 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
233 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5546 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
5546 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\bobthebuilder\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe
6061 INFO: Caching module hooks...
6061 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\BobTheBuilder\Desktop\build\build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\bobthebuilder\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\bobthebuilder\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\BobTheBuilder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\bobthebuilder\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\bobthebuilder\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\bobthebuilder\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 844, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\bobthebuilder\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\BobTheBuilder\Desktop\build\build.spec", line 17, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "c:\users\bobthebuilder\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 243, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\bobthebuilder\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\bobthebuilder\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 445, in assemble
    priority_scripts.append(self.graph.run_script(script))
  File "c:\users\bobthebuilder\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 201, in run_script
    self._top_script_node = super(PyiModuleGraph, self).run_script(pathname)
  File "c:\users\bobthebuilder\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1384, in run_script
    with open(pathname, 'rb') as fp:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\BobTheBuilder\\Desktop\\build\\build'
```

Normally on my physical windows PC it will make a 'Build' and 'dist' folder with the working application in the 'dist' folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up trying a few different versions of the command and "pyinstaller 'pyfile.py'" worked

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the command from CMD run as Administrator within your virtual machine? To clarify, I mean right-click run as admin rather than just running CMD while logged in as an admin account.

You could also try using LUA Buglight to check exactly what permissions are being denied to pyinstaller.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaron_margosis/2015/06/30/lua-buglight-2-3-with-support-for-windows-8-1-and-windows-10/

Comment: Also I just tried using LUA Buglight and it doesn't seem to work for command line apps